# Share internet on Mac with WEP

Tags: macos, wifi, airport, high-sierra, internet-sharing

I am on MacOS High Sierra. I need to share the internet connection from Thunderbolt though WiFi with WEP as the security protocol. But I cannot see WEP in the sharing options. I tried this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/504915/how-to-share-internet-on-mac-with-wep) but apparently, it is not working as well. Is WEP completely removed in High Sierra or is there is a way to achieve this?

PS: I must use WEP to connect to a rather old Embedded device.

Comment: WEP is so broken that it doesn't really provide additional security compared to an unsecured connection any longer. Does the embedded device *require* WEP?

Comment: @patrix yes. If I could  I would stay with `None`. But I am left with no choice than using WEP.